# Can I get network camera direction?

Tags: onvif

I am selecting a network camera.

It turned out that the network camera is standardized by ONVIF.
In the ONVIF standard, PTZ control gives speed and operating time.
I want to get the camera orientation (angle).

Can I get the camera orientation with the ONVIF standard?

Furthermore, I want to change the orientation of the camera by giving an orientation (angle).
First of all, is there any camera that can feed back the angle of the camera?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to get the camera orientation (angle).

You can look at the `GetStatus` onvif function to get the current position. It doesn't work with all onvif certified cameras for some reason... (I had trouble with Foscam and Amcrest cameras in the past)

https://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/imaging/wsdl/imaging.wsdl#op.GetStatus

> I want to change the orientation of the camera by giving an
>   orientation (angle).

You can look at the `AbsoluteMove` onvif function to set the position of your camera to the absolute values (angle) you want.

https://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/ptz/wsdl/ptz.wsdl#op.AbsoluteMove

Here's the list of all "available" functionalities of onvif. I say "available" because, just like the earlier `GetStatus`, some cameras will return you an error when calling them for some reason...

https://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/util/operationIndex.html

Comment: Thanks Louk. I figure out that I needed a relative table to calculate the angle from the absolute position value.