# Disabled IP PTZ camera auto focus using python-onvif-zeep

Tags: python, ip-camera, python-onvif

My PTZ camera auto focus and adjust images on pan-tilt-zoom and on some object appear in camera.
I want to disabled those features.

I'm using python-onvif-zeep library https://github.com/FalkTannhaeuser/python-onvif-zeep.git

The operation guide of onvif here
https://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/util/operationIndex.html

The specific function I want to send request is SetImagingSettings
https://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/imaging/wsdl/imaging.wsdl#op.SetImagingSettings

I've try to create the request as below

```
request = controller.imaging.create_type('SetImagingSettings')
video_sources = controller.media.GetVideoSources() # get video source to fetch token

request.VideoSourceToken = video_sources[0].token
request.ImagingSettings = {
    'Brightness': 200,
    'Focus': {
        'AutoFocusMode': 'MANUAL'
    }
}

controller.imaging.SetImagingSettings(request)
```

Without the 'Focus' part, the code work well that update the Brightness value.

My expectation: the imaging settings be update, that disabled auto focus.

But I get a general error said "zeep.exceptions.Fault: The requested settings are incorrect"
Thanks everyone!

Comment: Have you tried contacting the guys that made python-onvif-zeep directly? (:

I would suggest you to create an issue there!

https://github.com/FalkTannhaeuser/python-onvif-zeep/issues

Comment: There is also some chance that your ONVIF camera doesn't support the command you're trying to send... It happened to me a couple of times. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56642348/can-i-get-network-camera-direction/56672849#56672849

Comment: @LoukMouk Thanks you. I had checked Imaging GetOptions and GetCapasibilities.
It seem the camera provider does not support onvif set focus for imaging settings.

Answer (score 2):

Try to

1. Get Image Settings
2. Get Request to SetImageSetting:
3. Set into Request to SetImageSetting:ImagingSettings the response of firts step
4. Set the VideoTokenProfile
5. Send de request

> ```
> ptz         = mycam.create_ptz_service()
> media       = mycam.create_media_service()
> imaging     = mycam.create_imaging_service()
>
> requestGetImaging                      = imaging.create_type('GetImagingSettings')
> video_sources                          = media.GetVideoSources()
> requestGetImaging.VideoSourceToken     = video_sources[0]._token
>
> responseGetImageSettings  = imaging.GetImagingSettings(requestImaging)
>
>
> requestSetImaging                      = imaging.create_type('SetImagingSettings')
> requestSetImaging.VideoSourceToken     = video_sources[0]._token
> requestSetImaging.ImagingSettings      = responseGetImageSettings
> requestSetImaging.ImagingSettings.Brightness = 50
>
> print requestSetImaging
> imaging.SetImagingSettings(requestSetImaging)
> ```